# Question about calculating exponent of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, exponentiation, exponential-function

$V=R_{3}[X] $ and $T:V->V$ is a linear transformation : $T(p(x)) = p(x) + xp'(x)$

I need to find $e^{T(1+x+x^{2}-x^{3})}$

I don't understand how to do it? what does it mean to calculate exponent of vector? I know the method of doing it for a matrix, finding its Jordan form over the complex field etc.. but what to do here? thank you

Comment: Could you verify if perhaps the task was to compute $e^T(1+x+x^2−x^3)$, i.e., applying the exponential of the operator to the polynomial? This would require, as one variant, the eigendecomposition of the operator $T$ restricted to degree-$3$ polynomials.

Comment: you are right that was what I need to do, I know how to find e^T by using Jordan, but what's next?

Answer (score 0):

The expression $1+x+x^{2}-x^{3}$ is a third-degree polynomial in $x$.
The expression $T(1+x+x^{2}-x^{3})$ is also a third-degree polynomial in $x$.
You can evaluate such a polynomial at any given value of $x$.
So $e^{T(1+x+x^{2}-x^{3})}$ is a function of $x$ described as follows:

$$e^{T(1+x+x^{2}-x^{3})} = e^y$$

where $y = T(1+x+x^{2}-x^{3})$. That is, $y$ is the number obtained by evaluating the polynomial $T(1+x+x^{2}-x^{3})$ at a given value of $x$.